# Can i reactivate the loop from button click?

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to set $i to 0 again if i click a button?
I'm puzzled on how to actually re-print everything again.

Html

```
<html>

<head>
<input type="button" onclick="" value="reset">
<?php

        for($i=0; $i<12; $i++)
        {echo "Chocolate Rain";}

?>  
</head>

</html>
```

(I just want to know the main concept of how to do this, as i need to implement this concept into my application coding)

Comment: Sure, just set it inside a function, with a bit of modification it can be done.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, the answer is no. PHP is run on the server. Once it has run, you cannot modify it in the browser.

Comment: If you want a button click to activate something in PHP, it either has to reload the page or use AJAX.

Comment: My sentiments exactly ---^

Comment: if you have to print the same block of code use jquery's .html() or .clone() method see below links http://api.jquery.com/clone/ http://api.jquery.com/html/ for detail

Comment: How do i close a question?

Comment: Wait for someone to give you an "answer", for you to accept it as being the correct one.